# Rails namespaced routes - Windows vs Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on an old client application running under Rails 2.3.11 on Windows Server 2003. All the application relies on a simple catch-all route (Hell yeah!) :

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
```

I have some nested modules and everything is working fine on Windows (prod) and Mac OS (dev).

```
url_for(:controller=>'/settings/users', :action=>:index)
#=> Settings::Users#index
```

Recently I changed from Mac OS to Ubuntu 11.04. Everything works, except these nested routes.

```
url_for(:controller=>'/settings/users', :action=>:index)
#=> Settings#users
```

Does anyone have a clue about what is going on? Why is this problem Linux only?

Comment: what does `:controller => '/settings/users'` do?  maybe its taking that as an absolute filesystem path,

Comment: Nop. This is suppose to map to the controller 'Settings::User' with the action 'index'. My problem is that on my Linux system, it's mapping to the controller 'Settings' and the action 'users'... So no, it doesn't take that as an absolute filesystem path.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very likely that this is an OS-specific problem if it affects the routing in such a specific way. Is there any reason you're prefixing the controller name with `/`? Named routes avoid most of this mess by being very specific, so it's unfortunate you're left without them.

There's probably a slight difference in gem versions on the two systems, maybe something very subtle.

Comment: Gems are ok (unfortunately...), I checked. The problem is the same with and without the prefixed '/'. Thanks anyway.

Comment: On a long-shot, is the output of `rake routes` the same for both? You really don't have much routing going on there. You can also try and use the `assert_routing` functional test to try and verify the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

try somehting like this

```
 map.namespace :settigns do |settings|
   settings.connect '/:controller/:action/:id
 end
```

or something using map.namespace, that is how I do controllers in a module, except its different types of routes

```
 map.namespace :admin do |admin|
   admin.resources :reports, :only => [:new, :create ]
   admin.connect 'reports/generate/:action/*rest', :controller => 'reports'
   admin.resources :approval, :controller => 'approval', :only => [ :index, :create ] 
   admin.resource :home, :controller => 'home' 
 end
```

hope this helps